# Cannot read property "length" from undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays

I just started learning more about arrays, and the code doesn't seem to be working properly.

I'm trying to move two rows from one sheet to another based on the value of the a third row:

- If column 4 contains "Yes", then copy cells from from column 2 and 3, then move them to 'Sheet44'.

Any idea how to fix this?

Here is the code:

```
function AddRows() {

    var spreadsheet, targetSheet, sourceSheet, sourceValues, targetValues;

    spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    targetSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Sheet44");
    sourceSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Vlookup");
    sourceValues = sourceSheet.getRange(2, 2, 6, 2).getValues().filter(function (r) {
        return r\[2\] === 'Yes'
    });

    targetValues = targetSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
    targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, sourceValues.length, sourceValues[1].length).setValues(sourceValues);


};
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6mG5F.png)

Comment: You are accessing `sourceValues[1].length`. Does `sourceValues` have at least 2 items?

Comment: And what is this `[spreadsheet = ....][1]` syntax? It seems invalid

Comment: Not sure why the code went with " [ ". Sorry about that. The first part should be:
  
    var spreadsheet, targetSheet, sourceSheet, sourceValues, targetValues;
    
    spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    targetSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Sheet44");
    sourceSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Vlookup");
    sourceValues = sourceSheet.getRange(2, 2, 6, 2).getValues().filter(function (r) {
        return r[2] === 'Yes'
    });
  
And yes, sourceValues does have at least 2 items